# How to update a js cookie?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am making an html departments dropdown that gets options from a php database.

Every time an option is selected, a method is executed which retrieves the value of the selected option and then stores it into the cookie. the cookie is supposed to update every time a new option is selected, but instead it remains undefined. I intend to retrieve this cookie using a PHP variable so I can use it in SQL queries.

(PHP)

```
 <?php
// departments
$qy_dept = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT deptname FROM departments ORDER BY ID ASC");
                                    
if (!$qy_dept){
 die("error in departments SELECT query".$conn->error);
}

echo "
   <select name='dd-department' onchange='readDept()' required>
         <option value=''>Select Department</option>
";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qy_dept)) {
                   
     echo "<option value='$row[deptname]'";
     echo ">";
     echo "$row[deptname]";
     echo "</option>";
     echo "";
}

echo " </select> "; 
echo " <br> ";
echo "selected is $_COOKIE[selectedDept]";

// $deptchoice can be accessed by the job titles query
if (isset($_COOKIE['selectedDept'])) {
    $deptchoice = $_COOKIE['selectedDept'];
    echo "<button onclick='location.href='res/script/dept-Edit.php?editdept=$deptchoice''>"."Edit \"".$deptchoice."\""."</button>";
} else {
    $deptchoice = '';
}
?>
```

(JavaScript)

```
function readDept(){
    const dp_dept = document.querySelector("select[name='dd-department']");
    let dept_selected = dp_dept.options[dp_dept.selectedIndex].value;

    if (dept_selected != ''){
        // FIXME only php session id showing
        document.cookie = `selectedDept=${dept_selected}; expires=0; path=/departments.php;`;
        
        console.log(`Expected value in cookie: ${dept_selected}`);
        console.log(document.cookie);
    }
}
```

I tried to manually set the cookie's value like this just to see if it the cookie was receiving anything:

```
 document.cookie = `selectedDept=HR; expires=0; path=/departments.php;`;
```

but when I do console.log(document.cookie); all that is printed on the console is the session ID, not the selectedDept and its value. Which means that the cookie is not updating at all.

Does it have something to do with the expiry?

Comment: Might I suggest you look at AJAX as a better option

Comment: My concern with AJAX is that it is not open-source. Can I use jQuery to do something like this?

Comment: Open source? Do you know what you are talking about? AJAX is a concept implementation, a way of getting a web page to communicate with a server without needing to submit the page. Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

What is path=/departments.php?
Path, in 99%, must be /
You use other than / if the cookie must be valid only inside a subdomain, a different "resource" like directories, or specifically for a "file" but each of them must exists.
You cannot set a cookie for /js/a_file.js if "a_file.js" doesn't exists

Comment: path=/departments.php

For the path part I wanted the cookie valid for only one php page

Comment: Does the path really exists on the server? Or is build upon a rewrite or kind of?
I mean, is http://www.yourserver.com/departments.php a real file?

Comment: Yes, but for now this is on a localhost

My main folder which contains all my files is "isdb-files-main" and there is a subfolder "res" with three subfolders afterwards: "css", "photo", & "script"

departments.php (php snippet is from here) is in isdb-files-main

deptjobtitle.js (the attached js code) is in isdb-filesmain/res/script

Comment: So, which is the real uri address on the browser?

If I have a www.mydomain.com/pages/index.php AND www.mydomain.com/pages/default.php AND i set a cookie "selectedDept" for "path=/pages/default.php", when I visit www.mydomain.com/pages/index.php I don't have the cookie "selectedDept" but everytime I go to www.mydomain.com/pages/default.php I'll have the "selectedDept" cookie.
If www.mydomain.com/pages/default.php DOES NOT EXISTS, the cookie will not be set

Comment: The full path for departments page is
"localhost/isdb-files-main/departments.php"
and when I am inside here I do not receive the cookie
if the path is set to "path=/departments.php;" even when I refresh the page

So instead I followed your suggestion and changed path into "path=/" and the cookie is received by departments.php
So I have a new problem: the cookie does not update until I refresh the page.